# I want to show objects of NSMutableArray in two different colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

There is an NSMutableArray "onlinevalarr" in which i have offline and online as values.
I want to show offline in red colour and online value in green colour.
This is my code:

`{
    for (NSString * str in onlinevalarr)
    {
        if ([str isEqualToString:@"online"])
        {
            NSLog(@"online");
            cell.online.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
        else if ([str isEqualToString:@"offline"])
        {
            NSLog(@"offline");
            cell.online.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
    }
}`

But with this code either i am getting all the values in red or all in green.

Comment: are you getting right logs ?

Comment: all values are shown as label in custom cell.

Comment: yes m getting right logs,it is entering in right if-else if conditions,but text colour is not changing

Comment: itz like if last value of array is offline then the whole array appears in red colour and if last is online then all are in green colour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about what your code is doing.

You have a for loop that loops through ALL The elements in your array and sets the current cell's color based on on the current array element. As you go through your for loop you set the current cell's color to different values, and then once you're done, the cell will have the color for the last entry in your array. That doesn't make sense.

If this code is from your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, then you want to get the row of the current cell, use it as an index into your array, and then use that to determine the color for the current cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try using different cell identifiers for each cell.
Ex: "OnlineCellIdentifier" and "OfflineCellIdentifier

Answer (score 0):

After updating the colour, reload the data for that cell

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
if ([(NSString*)[onlinevarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"online"]){
    NSLog(@"online");
    cell.online.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}else if ([[(NSString*)[onlinevarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"offline"]){
    NSLog(@"offline");
    cell.online.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

P.S. This code is to be kept in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

And please, don't just paste the code, understand it. This is the code-version of @DuncanC's answer.

Comment: @aksh1t, I suggest NOT posting exact code. At the OP's level of learning, he/she **is** going to cut-and-paste it without understanding what it does. Note that he accepted your answer, not mine. I told him what was wrong with his code and how to fix it. You provided drop-in code.

Comment: @DuncanC I thought that posting some code would make things easier for the OP. Well, I get it that most probably he/she will just paste the code without learning from it and return with some other question eventually, rather than learning from the mistake. I will take care henceforth to make the OP understand rather than just provide drop-in code.

Comment: @DuncanC i saw ur answere and start trying implementing it,but when i came back to review it again,by that time u deleted your answere.

Comment: @AV121, I did not delete my answer. It's still there.